# Training accuracy on Naive Bayes in Python

Tags: python, classification, naivebayes

I'm running a Naive Bayes model and can print my testing accuracy but not the training accuracy

```
#import libraries
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

#Naive Bayes model
gNB = GaussianNB()
gNB.fit(X_train, y_train)

nb_predict = gNB.predict(X_test)

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, nb_predict))
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, nb_predict)
average_accuracy = np.mean(y_test == nb_predict) * 100
print("The average_accuracy is {0:.1f}%".format(average_accuracy))

#PRINTS The average_accuracy is 39.0%

#try to print training accuracy
print(metrics.classification_report(y_train, X_train))
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, X_train)
average_accuracy = np.mean(y_train == X_train) * 100
print("The average_accuracy is {0:.1f}%".format(average_accuracy))
```

When I try to use the same code I used for the testing accuracy for the training accuracy, I get an error for the training accuracy.

## We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multiclass-multioutput targets
```

What code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score expects 1d array for y_true  and y_pred. So, in your code below

```
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, X_train)
```

y_train and X_train should be 1 dimensional. But X_train is not 1d array I think. Thats why the error occurs.
Read this doc: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

to measure the accuracy of your model for training data  after fitting your model you need to get predictions from train data
Then find the accuracy:

```
y_predict_for_trainData = gNB.predict(X_train)
accuracy_For_TrainData = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, y_predict_for_trainData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the doc. Is there another way to get the training accuracy if y_train and X_train are not 1d?

Comment: do you want to measure the accuracy of your model for training data ?

Comment: Yes I was needing to measure the accuracy of the model for training data. Your added code worked perfectly!